# How to add iteration numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

my question is about adding loops in python
I am trying to add iteration numbers like summation of all iteration results
For example

```
first iteration
a = 10
b = 5
a = a + b = 15
c = a = 15
second iteration
    a = 15
    b = 5
    a = a + b = 20
    c = a1 + a2 = 35

I know to iterate using for loop which is like this

for i in range(2)
    a = 10
    b = 5
    a = a + b

which gives a = 20 
but how to get c which is adding iteration results
```

Comment: x = 2                                                                                                          
    for i in range(x):
    a = y+z
    y = a+z ..... c = a+y for each iteration.. I need like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=10
b=5
c=0
for i in range(2):
    a = a + b
    c = c + a

print a
print c
```

Above one gives results of a and c

Comment: dude you just proved the quote 'Simplest are always the best' thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can define your variable outside your `for` loop to update it with the sum of each iteration

```
a_values = [10, 15]
b_values = [5, 5]
c = 0
for a, b in zip(a_values, b_values):
    c += a + b

print(c)
35
```

Comment: how about simply `c = sum(a_values+b_values)`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis In this case that would happen to work because their operation is `a+b` but if it were any other operation e.g. `a-b` that wouldn't be quite the right answer, although converting `a_values` and `b_values` to `numpy.array` would make that technique work trivially too

Comment: for a, b in zip(a_values, b_values):
    c += a + b   I tried this but it says float is not iterable

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I tried that too , it says float is not iterable error

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are quite confused OP. Why don't you just do this instead:

```
a = 10
b = 5
c  = sum(a+b for _ in range(2))
```

The problem with your version is that after calculating `a` during the first iteration, you re-assign its value to `10` in the second. Your loop would work with some modifications:

```
a = 10
b = 5
c = 0
for i in range(2)
    c += a + b
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need any loop if you apply some basic arithmetic:

```
print(a + n * b)
print(a * n + (n*(n+1))//2 * b)
```

With `a = 10`, `b = 5` and `n = 2`, it outputs:

```
20
35
```